# Early 2011 MacBook Pro Memory Upgrade - What are the SO-DIMM memory specs?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, upgrade

What are the exact specs when shopping for early 2011 MacBook Pro SO-DIMM memory? I'll be uprading to the maximum of 8GB.

Comment: The 2011 MacBook Pros can actually handle 16GB, despite apple's statements. (See: http://blog.macsales.com/9394-macbook-pro-2011-12gb-and-16gb-memory-upgrades-benchmarked )

Comment: Mostly, 8GB SO-DIMMs are just ridiculously expensive (~$800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple Support:

> - Double Data Rate Small Outline Dual Inline Memory Module (DDR3) format
> - 67.6mm x 30mm (1.18 inch)
> - 2 GB or 4 GB
> - 204-pin
> - PC3-10600 DDR3 1333 MHz type RAM

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1270

Comment: I can confirm that 1066 MHZ works without any problems with latest i7 2011. I didn't test if there are any performance issues, but at least it is stable.